# Скругление уголков в carousel от Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, javascript, css

Не получается настроить скругленные уголки в carousel от Twitter Bootstrap
сначала уголки появляются, но когда карусель начинает двигаться, они то пропадают, то снова появляются  
http://jsfiddle.net/CRzjv/33/ 
подскажите, как это можно решить?

Comment: Начнем с того, что пример по ссылке - нерабочий.

Comment: хз, он когда работает, когда нет, не знаю, с чем связано.

Answer (score 2):

```
.teaser img {
    width: 722px;
    height: 219px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CRzjv/35/

Comment: не, ну это понятно, что можно скруглить уголки у самих картинок, но интересовало именно у общей обертки сделать скругленные уголки.